# Text font family not showing the £ sign correctly

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

I am using the css text font "Century Gothic, Arial, Courier New, Sans-Serif" for my text on a webpage, however whenever I use the £ character, it does not show correctly on browsers (browsers test on are Firefox, Explorer, Chrome & Safari).

HMTL:

```
<span>£</span>
```

SPAN CSS:

```
font-family: Century Gothic, Arial, Courier New, Sans-Serif;
```

The above £ text shows as a question mark within a black diamond. Does anyone know why this is happening? Or do I just need to pick a different font family to display £ signs? All other text/characters on the page using the same font family show correctly

Comment: Does the encoding of your file match the one advertised (utf-8)? If you save your file as ISO-8859-15 or any other encoding and the browser expects utf-8, it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `&pound;` for the £ sign.
it will show correctly on all the browsers.
for eg.

**CSS**:

```
body { font-family:Century Gothic, Arial, Courier New, Sans-Serif;}
```

**HTML**:

```
<span>&pound;</span>
```

Comment: excellent that has worked a treat - thank you for teaching me this trick Navtosh

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `metacharset` to your `<head>`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

[image: Check this working live preview snap]

Comment: Thanks Ben, but I already have <meta charset="utf-8"> in the head of my HMTL

Comment: Is it a type `HMTL` if not change to `HTML`

Comment: No that was a typo, its HTML

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> </head>

Comment: Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/bfvqd9wz/) everything goes well

Comment: remove the semicolon `;` next to your `doctype`